# How to get distinct users from SPList in c# from list having people and group column?

Tags: development, visual-web-part, splistitemcollection

My Team Discussion list having the column "`AppreciatedTo`" of type `People and Group`. Whereas I need to fetch the distinct users in current year (created date also there) in visual webpart in c#. Adding entry to team discussion from another visual webpart which is working fine. But how to get above specified conditional list of users using linq?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Then post the code

Comment: Yes I did but making changes in code, so cannot paste it now. but couldn't get expected.